# Printer status return wrong value

Tags: c#, network-printers

I am trying to get the status of a network printer. I tried WMI code as this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6069/How-to-Check-if-your-Printer-is-Connected-using-C) says. But even if I removed the network cable, it always goes to the else part.

Here is the code I tried :

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new 
             ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

string printerName = "";

foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcher.Get())
{
    printerName = printer["Name"].ToString().ToLower();

    if (printer["WorkOffline"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true") && printer["Default"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true"))

    {
       string s = "Printer  offline" + printerName;
       listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }
    else
    {
        // printer is not offline
        //   Console.WriteLine("Your Plug-N-Play printer is connected.");

        string s = "Printer found and is online " + printerName;
        listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }
```

Comment: you have `ToLower` and then `Offline` ? you see why it would always be hitting the else part

Comment: +1 That is a good observation. But I printed the value.Its always false.

Comment: @V4Vendetta hi the question is edited. check the condition now

Comment: Workoffline will help you know if the prints can be queued up or not, i guess you need to use [`PrinterStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the condition

```
printer["PrinterState"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("Offline")
// this would mean offline == Offline which would be false
```

you would need the comparison in lower case, you have a typo Offline has a <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> `O`

Answer (score 1):

the comparison could be not right... 'cause the statement

`ConsoleWriteLine(printer["PrinterState"].ToString());`

returns "0" when the printer is on line, and "128" when this fault due any reason (power off, uninstalled, cable conection, network troubles, etc)

the right comparisons must  be:

`printer["PrinterState"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("128")` for off line

`printer["PrinterState"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("0")` for on line